# Microsoft Login. You can't get there from here. Conditional access. Require approved client app

Tags: azure-active-directory

Our azure active directory application needs delegated "Calendars.Read" permission to read some information from the user's calendar after the login. But when I set up login scope to "Calendars.Read" and try to login in native Android app I get an error:

> You can't get there from here
>
> It looks like you're trying to open this resource with an app that
> hasn't been approved by your IT department. Ask them for a list of
> approved applications.

Our tenant has conditional access on Office 365 (preview) with a "Require approved client app" in the Grant section. If review information mark near "Require approved client app" checkbox item we will see a list of trusted applications.

Does it mean that login with this scope is only available from those applications?
Does it possible to make our application trusted to some tenants?
What is the concept to handle the cases when your application needs access to the Office 365 but is prohibited by the admin of a tenant by  "Require approved client app" checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. The admin has created a policy which requires approved client app under Conditional Access. See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/app-based-conditional-access#scenario-1-office-365-apps-require-an-approved-client-app).You can find the list of approved client apps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/concept-conditional-access-grant#require-approved-client-app).

The Azure AD application you are using to access O365 is not an approved client app.

This policy only allows approved client apps to access O365 from Mobile app. We cannot add your own Azure AD app into the approved client apps. The policy needs to be strictly observed. If your tenant has enabled it, you cannot bypass it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So to make it clear. There is no way to give the custom application access to an app that is restricted with "Require approved client app". Is it correct?

Comment: @JoeBlack You are right. Unless the custom application is not Android or IOS app.

Comment: @JoeBlack I hope my answer has clarified this question. If you have any questions, please let me know at any time. If it's helpful, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: We have this problem on our android and ios applications. We are trying to log in to the android app and then we see this error.  The main problem that it is not possible to log in with it, because our mobile application, seems, is not trusted. You said, "Unless the custom application is not Android or IOS app".  Where I can get some information in case when a custom application is an android or IOS app?

Comment: @JoeBlack Based on the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/app-based-conditional-access#scenario-1-office-365-apps-require-an-approved-client-app), the policy prevents untrusted android or IOS app to access O365 data. I don't quite understand "Where I can get some information" you said, but if you want to access some information which is not in O365, it should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

After long discussions with the MS specialists, we figured out that there is no possible way to log into our app with MS login when a specific tenant has the "Approved client app" enabled. MS is going to provide something that will help to log in by using MS login when the "Approved client app is enabled" in the first chapter of 2021.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this issue, and are using the Chrome with the right extension version, and the correct Windows version, and the device is domain joined (thus meeting all of the stated criteria), you can resolve this by clicking on the Windows 10 accounts Chrome extension icon and completing any login prompts (if they even show up).

[image]

That should open a tab with office.com and show that you are now logged in.   At that point you can relaunch the shortcut or link that had originally given the "You can't get there from here" message and be able to continue as originally expected.